# FileNotFoundError while following hyperledger build-your-first-network documentation

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, read-the-docs

Throughout my developing career, I have never asked any questions, so this is my first time :)

I've been reading the docs on [hyperledger build-your-first-network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#start-the-network) and i'm having this error:

> ERROR: .FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './docker-compose-etcdraft2.yaml' 
>   in #Start the network section as i linked before. 
>   The command is: docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml -f docker-compose-etcdraft2.yaml up -d

I have tried with root and it gives the same error message. 
I have managed to go through the documentation flawlessly until this point.

Can I have some support from a more experienced developer?

Thank you for your attention so far :)

Comment: Can you see the `docker-compose-etcdraft2.yaml` file in your parent first-network directory?

Comment: no, it is not :(

Comment: Please clone the repo from [github](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples)